# grep for the particular bytes and put into columns from a file to a new file {shell script]

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a file which contains several paragraphs as below:

```
[730480.910190] [MACSTATUSIND] ACTIND_ParseMACSTATUS:
[730480.910205] fe 0a 39 01 0a 00 51 e7 ba 9d c7 0d 00 00 00 00  ..9...Q....
[730480.910220] 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ...........
[730480.910233] 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 xx xx xx xx xx xx  .....:bC.B.
[730480.910247] xx xx yy yy yy yy yy yy zz zz 64 34 e8 ff 00 00  ......d4...
```

from above data, for each paragraph i want to make three columns:

```
xxxxxxxx | yyyyyy |  zzzz
         |        |       
         |        |
```

and then store those rows in a different/new file.

I tried using grep and cut, but it's too lengthy and don't have enough idea about sed & awk commands.

How to solve above scenario using sed and awk commands!!

Comment: There is no question here, just an exclamation.

Comment: This question is not well explained.  Is it the case that each "paragraph" is 5 lines long and you want to extract data from specific locations?  What denotes the beginning of a new "paragraph"?  Is each of your output streams a fixed amount of data for each paragraph?

Comment: Why do you want 3 columns?  It appears you really want 3 distinct output files and forming 3 columns is unnecessary.

Comment: @WilliamPursell : yes all paragraph are 5 lines long i want to extract the xx/yy//zz bytes from specific locations as cited in question. The beginning of each paragraph statrt with " [MACSTATUSIND] ACTIND_ParseMACSTATUS:". I want 3 columns to be written to a new file after extraction

Comment: [edit] your question to explain exactly how you could get the output you posted from the input you posted or fix your example if you can't. `i want to make three columns` - out of what?

Answer (score 1):

Consider this a 'code golf' solution, at least I had some fun with it;)

```
<file sed -n '/MACSTAT/ {n;n;n;p;n;p}' | 
  cut -c 17-63 | 
  paste -d' ' - - | 
  cut -c 31-78 | 
  sed -e 's/ /|/8' -e 's/ /|/13' | 
  tr -d ' '
```

I suggest to remove the parts of the pipe from the end to figure out what exactly the commands do to the input. In general the first `sed` finds the header, skips three lines, prints the next two. Then `cut` keeps only the hexprint. Then `paste` joins each two consecutive lines into one. Then `cut` takes out only the required bytes. Then `sed` substitutes particular spaces with column separators. Then `tr` removes the remaining spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this sed (GNU sed) 4.4

```
sed -nE '
/\[MACSTATUSIND] ACTIND_ParseMACSTATUS:/N;N;N;N
    # get 5 lines if the first contain MACSTAT...
s/.*\n[^ ]* //
    # keep only the last line after the first space
s/ //g
    # remove all spaces
s/(.{4})(.{12})(.{4}).*/\1|\2|\3/p
    # keep only the 20 char you want and
    # format them in 3 columns with delimiter |
' infile
```